# Update a d3.js (v5) selection bound with double nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a double nested data set in d3. I want to create a scatter plot to be updated for each value of the first key ("time" variable), but the data of each point is bound to the values of he second key ("space" variable). So, to be clear, each point should be translated to new coordinates and its radius must be updated too.

Here is a data sample (in file "prosperLoanData.csv")

```
BorrowerState,LoanOriginationDate,LoanOriginalAmount,LenderYield
AK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,1000,0.1
AK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,2000,0.11
AK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,1500,0.09
AK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,500,0.1
AK,2008-01-01 00:00:01,2500,0.07
AK,2008-01-01 00:00:01,3000,0.06
AK,2008-01-01 00:00:01,3500,0.0652
OK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,4000,0.08
OK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,4100,0.081
OK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,4500,0.0812
OK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,4600,0.0799
OK,2007-01-01 00:00:01,3900,0.08
OK,2008-01-01 00:00:01,5000,0.05
```

And here is my code. I though that deleting the YearGroups1.exit().remove() was enough, but it is not. I can not properly select the circles and rebind them to the new dataset (at the second nested level). Can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <style>

      div.tooltip { 
        position: absolute;     
        text-align: center;     
        width: 180px;          
        height: 45px;         
        padding: 2px;       
        font: 12px sans-serif;    
        background: lightsteelblue; 
        border: 0px;    
        border-radius: 8px;     
        pointer-events: none;     
    }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      </script>
  </head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  /*
    Use D3 to load the loan data
    */

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

// load data
d3.csv("prosperLoanData.csv").then(function(data) {

  // Setting global parameters

  "use strict";

  //    ----> Margin & size
  var margin = 75,
    width = 1400 - margin,
    height = 600 - margin,
    op = 0.5,
    years = [2007, 2008];

  //    ----> Format for strings
  var formatDec = d3.format(".0f"),
    formatper = d3.format(".2%"),
    formatM = d3.format("\$.2s");


  // change string (from CSV) into number format
  data.forEach( function(d) {
    d["Year"] = parseTime(d.LoanOriginationDate).getYear() + 1900;
    d["LoanOriginalAmount"] = +d["LoanOriginalAmount"];
    d["LenderYield"] = +d["LenderYield"];
    // debugger
    return d; });

  // Function definition

  // function update() {};
  function key_func(d) {
                return d['key'];
            }

  // FIXED PART

  // Define the svg element
  var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin)
      .attr("height", height + margin);

  // Define the div for the tooltip
  var div = d3.select("body").append("div") 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")       
    .style("opacity", 0);

  // Data preprocessing - grouping

  var nested_year = d3.nest()
    .key( function(d) { return d.Year } )
    .key( function(d) { return d.BorrowerState })
    .rollup( function(points) {

      // debugger
          var mean_loan = d3.mean(points, function(d) { return d.LoanOriginalAmount; } );
          var mean_lenderyield = d3.mean(points, function(d) { return d.LenderYield; } );
          // var std_loan = d3.deviation(points, function(d) { return d.LoanOriginalAmount; } );
          var sum_loan = d3.sum(points, function(d) { return d.LoanOriginalAmount; } );

          var max_loan = d3.max(points, function(d) { return d.LoanOriginalAmount; } );
          var min_loan = d3.min(points, function(d) { return d.LoanOriginalAmount; } );

          var max_ly = d3.max(points, function(d) { return d.LenderYield; } );
          var min_ly = d3.min(points, function(d) { return d.LenderYield; } );

          // debugger

          return {
            "meanLoan" : mean_loan,
            "meanLenderyield" : mean_lenderyield,
            // "stdLoan" : std_loan,
            "sumLoan" : sum_loan,
            };

           }

         )
    .entries(data);

  // Determining X/Y Max & Min

  var LOA_E1 = d3.min(nested_year, function(d) {return d3.min(d.values, function(da) { return da.value.meanLoan; });})
  var LOA_E2 = d3.max(nested_year, function(d) {return d3.max(d.values, function(da) { return da.value.meanLoan; });})

  var LY_E1 = d3.min(nested_year, function(d) {return d3.min(d.values, function(da) { return da.value.meanLenderyield; });})
  var LY_E2 = d3.max(nested_year, function(d) {return d3.max(d.values, function(da) { return da.value.meanLenderyield; });})

  var LenderYield_Extent        = [LY_E1  , LY_E2 ];
  var LoanOriginalAmount_Extent = [LOA_E1 , LOA_E2];

  // Creating a scale
  var XScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([margin , width])
    .domain([ 1.05 * LenderYield_Extent[0] - 0.05 * LenderYield_Extent[1] , 
              1.05 * LenderYield_Extent[1] - 0.05 * LenderYield_Extent[0] ] );

  // debugger

  var YScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height , margin])
    .domain([ 0, 1.025 * LoanOriginalAmount_Extent[1]]);

  var SUM_LOAN_Extent = [70E3 , 1.2E7]; // d3.extent(red_data.value, d => d.value.sumLoan);

  var radius = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .domain(SUM_LOAN_Extent)
    .range([3,0.375 * margin/2]);

  // Creating axis

  var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(XScale)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2%"));

  var y_axis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(YScale)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".0f"));

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(x_axis);

  svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + margin + ",0)")
    .call(y_axis);

  // Text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")             
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + (width/2 + margin) + " ," + 
                         (height + margin/2) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size", 20)
    .text("Mean lender yield (percentage)");

  // Text label for the y axis
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size", 20)
    .text("Mean loan original amount [US dollars]"); 

  // Creating gridlines

function make_x_gridlines() {   
    return d3.axisBottom(XScale)
        .ticks(5);
};

function make_y_gridlines() {   
    return d3.axisLeft(YScale)
        .ticks(5);
};

svg.append("g")     
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-(height - 1 * margin ))
      .tickFormat(""));

svg.append("g")     
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + margin + ",0)")
    .call(make_y_gridlines()
      .tickSize(-(width -  1 * margin ))
      .tickFormat(""));

// Add legend

var DELTA = SUM_LOAN_Extent[1] - SUM_LOAN_Extent[0];

var valuesToShow = [SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 0.00 * DELTA, SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 0.25 * DELTA ,
                    SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 0.50 * DELTA, SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 0.75 * DELTA ,
                    SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 1.00 * DELTA ];

var xCircle = width + 0.35 * margin;
var xLabel = 200;
var yCircle = 150;

var legend = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","legend")
  .attr("trasform","translate(" + (width - 100) + "," + 20 + ")" )
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(valuesToShow)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

legend.append("circle")
  .attr("cy", function(d,i) { 
     return (i+1)* 0.4 * yCircle + radius(d)/2; })
  .attr("cx", xCircle)
  .attr("r", function(d) {
     return radius(d); })
  .attr("stroke","black")
  .attr("stroke-width",1.)
  .attr("opacity", op);

// Add legend: labels
svg.selectAll("legend")
  .data(valuesToShow)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr('x', function(d,i){ return width + 0.55 * margin; } )
    .attr('y', function(d,i){ return (i+1)* 0.4 * yCircle + radius(d)/2 } )
    .text( function(d){ return formatM(d) } )
    .style("font-size", 10)
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle');

svg.append("text")
    .attr('x', 0.98 * xCircle )
    .attr('y', 0.15 * yCircle )
    .text( "Size = " )
    .style("font-size", 12.5)
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle');

svg.append("text")
    .attr('x', 0.98 * xCircle )
    .attr('y', 0.15 * yCircle + 10 )
    .text( "Total loan" )
    .style("font-size", 12.5)
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle');

svg.append("text")
    .attr('x', 0.98 * xCircle )
    .attr('y', 0.15 * yCircle + 20)
    .text( "amount (US \$)" )
    .style("font-size", 12.5)
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle');

// Add color legend

var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain([0, 1, 2])
  .range(["blue", "green" , "black"]);

var stat = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain([0, 1, 2])
  .range(["CA", "TX" , "Others"]);

var aaa = [ SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 1.00 * DELTA , SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 1.00 * DELTA, SUM_LOAN_Extent[0] + 1.00 * DELTA];

var legend1 = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class","legend")
  .attr("trasform","translate(" + (width - 100) + "," + 20 + ")" )
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(aaa)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

legend1.append("circle")
  .attr("cy", function(d,i) { //debugger
     return (6+i)* 0.4 * yCircle + radius(d)/2; })
  .attr("cx", xCircle)
  .attr("r", function(d) {
     return radius(d); })
  .attr("fill", function(d,i){ return colors(i)})
  .attr("opacity", op);

// Add legend: labels
svg.selectAll(".legend1")
  .data(aaa)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr('x', function(d,i){ return width + 0.55 * margin; } )
    .attr('y', function(d,i){ return (6+i)* 0.4 * yCircle + radius(d)/2 } )
    .text( function(d,i){ return stat(i) } )
    .style("font-size", 10)
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle');

// Appending first circles

// Accessing 1st group

var YearGroups = svg.selectAll(".YearGroups")
    .data(nested_year, key_func)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "YearGroups");

// Accessing 2nd group

var circles = YearGroups.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d){ 
      return d.values 
    })
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return XScale(d.value.meanLenderyield) } )
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return YScale(d.value.meanLoan       ) } )
    .attr("r" , function(d) { return radius(d.value.sumLoan        ) } )
    .attr("fill" , function(d) { if 
                                                    (d.key == "CA") {return "blue"}
                                                  if (d.key == "TX") {return "green"}
                                                  else
                                                    { return "black" }})
    .attr("opacity" , op);

// debugger

// VARIABLE PART

function update(year) {

              var filt = nested_year.filter(function(d) {return d.key == year;} );

              var YearGroups1 = svg.selectAll(".YearGroups")
                .data(filt, key_func);

              YearGroups1.exit().remove();

              var circles = YearGroups1.enter().append('g')
                               .attr("class", "YearGroups").selectAll('circle')
                               .data(function(d){ return d.values });

              var CircPl = circles.enter()
                     .append("circle")
                     .transition()
                     .duration(500)
                     .attr("cx", function(d) { // debugger
                                               return XScale(d.value.meanLenderyield); })
                     .attr("cy", function(d) { return YScale(d.value.meanLoan       ); })
                     .attr("r" , function(d) { return radius(d.value.sumLoan        ); })
                     .attr("fill" , function(d) { if 
                                                    (d.key == "DC") {return "blue"}
                                                  if (d.key == "AR") {return "green"}
                                                  else
                                                    { return "black" }})
                     .attr("opacity" , op)
                     .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                       div.transition()
                          .duration(200)
                          .style("opacity", .9);    
                       div.html("Lender yield : " + formatper(d.value.meanLenderyield) + "<br/>"  + 
                                "Loan original amount : " + formatDec(d.value.meanLoan) + " $ <br/>"  + 
                                "State : " + d.key)
                          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")   
                          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");  
                     })          
                     .on("mouseout", function(d) {   
                       div.transition()    
                         .duration(500)    
                         .style("opacity", 0);
                     });

              CircPl


              // debugger

              // Chart Title
              svg.selectAll(".Title").remove()

              svg
                .append("text")
                .attr("class","Title")
                .attr("x", (margin + width) / 2)
                .attr("y", margin / 2)
                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-size", "32px")
                .text("US Loans per State in " + year); // Title updated
  }

var year_idx = 0;

var year_interval = setInterval(function() {
  update(years[year_idx]);

  year_idx++;

  if(year_idx >= years.length) {
      clearInterval(year_interval);
  }
}, 1000);


});

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the issue (thanks Myles C. from Udacity Mentor team).

In fact, the data to be accessed where easily stored in a dummy variable that has been used for data binding afterwards and the *.merge()* statement is used to update both to all circles.

```
function update_video(year) {

    var filt = nested_year.filter(function(d) {
      return d.key == year;
    });

    var data = filt[0].values

    // Selection and Bind Data
    const update = YearGroups.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data);

    var upd = update.enter()
      .select("circle")
      .merge(update)
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("class", "node_circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return XScale(d.value.meanLenderyield);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return YScale(d.value.meanLoan);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return radius(d.value.sumLoan);
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.key == "CA") { return "blue";}
        if (d.key == "TX") { return "green";}
        else { return "black"}
      });

    // Command necessary to remove States that are not available in the
    // database for that year
    update.exit().remove();


    // Chart Title
    svg.selectAll(".Title").remove();

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "Title")
      .attr("x", (margin + width) / 2)
      .attr("y", margin / 2)
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "32px")
      .text("US Loans per State in " + year); // Title update
  };
```

With this function, each circle is updated, regardless of the state (second key of nested data); the .exit().remove() command has been used to remove all points not bound to data.

Afterward, a second function is used to let the user choose a year and update the circles without transitions, but adding tooltips to get data information hoovering the points with the mouse.

```
function update_with_tooltip(year) {

    var filt = nested_year.filter(function(d) {
      return d.key == year;
    });

    var data = filt[0].values;

    // Selection and Bind Data
    const update = YearGroups.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data);

    // Update and merge
    var upd = update.enter()
      .select("circle")
      .merge(update)
      .attr("class", "node_circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return XScale(d.value.meanLenderyield);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return YScale(d.value.meanLoan);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return radius(d.value.sumLoan);
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.key == "CA") { return "blue";}
        if (d.key == "TX") { return "green";}
        else { return "black"}
      })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);    

        div.html("Lender yield : " + formatper(d.value.meanLenderyield) + 
          "<br/>"  + "Loan original amount : " + formatDec(d.value.meanLoan)
          + " $ <br/>"  + "State : " + d.key)
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()    
          .duration(500)    
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });

    // Command necessary to remove States that are not available in the
    // database for that year
    update.exit().remove();

    // Chart Title
    svg.selectAll(".Title").remove();

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "Title")
      .attr("x", (margin + width) / 2)
      .attr("y", margin / 2)
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "32px")
      .text("US Loans per State in " + year); // Title update
  }
```